# Invalid value for the configfile paramter of the generationapplication manifest task

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have an issue when i want to publish a project i receive the error message

"obj\debug\project.exe.config;obj\Debug\project.exe.config"is an invalid value for the "ConfigFile" parameter of the "GenerateApplicationManifest" task.
Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type
"Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".
I have searched about the issue and  i found i have to uncheck "Enable ClickOnce security settings" at Properties/Security but still have the same problem cannot publish my project.. ?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gZzh.png)

Answer (score 40):

Probably the transformation file is wrong. It seems like it is trying to add multiple config files at the same time.

Have you tried to look at your transformation file? It could be helpful, if you could post the transformation file.

Also this article, seems like there is a solution [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/163732/visual-studio-wont-compile-project-with-config-for.html#reply-183829) for a similar issue:

> I ran into this same problem. What fixed it for me was changing the line in the transform from above
>
> from
>
> ```
> <AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="app.config" />
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> <AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="@(AppConfigWithTargetPath)"/>
> ```

The `AppConfigWithTargetPath` config parameter can be found in the **.csproj** file.

Comment: My transformation config is default* nothing more i will try it ,but i think that is gonna work my friend,thank you

Comment: Switched from 2015 to 2017 and this fixed builds for me.

Comment: this is in the project file you need to edit it, this detail should be added..

Comment: @Crick3t: What transformation file are you referring to? This issue was in my project (.csproj) file. Thanks, Seabizkit.

Comment: @Suncat2000: OP's original issue was with a task, which suggests there is an issue with the transformation or the build file that is using the AppConfigWithTargetPath parameter which is in the .csproj file. (Hence the solution above).

The build file is the one that end's with .targets (if you have one) and the transformation file can be any file, like .config where you set up transformation rules, like xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"

Comment: @Crick3t, I must have read, and skipped over this answer about 5 times because I didn't realise where this parameter was. Perhaps you could edit your main answer to include that the AppConfigWithTargetPath parameter is in the csproj file. Or maybe we should all just read a little better. Thanks!

Comment: @russelrillema I have added, hopefully it will save time for others. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This was part of a transformation target that was added to my project file. The `<ItemGroup>` section for specifying the target path was trying to remove the normal configuration file, but that filename also should have included the target path. Changing `App.config` to `@(AppConfigWithTargetPath)` allowed the normal file to be removed and replaced with my transformed file and completing the build successfully.

Comment: This was my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Had to do it for both the AppConfigWithTargetPath `Remove` and `Include` settings, then it solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

Got the same error on my WPF project (Visual Studio 2013), no idea why. I solved it disabling the `ClickOnce` security settings.

- Project `Properties`
- `Security` tab
- Untick "`Enable ClickOnce security settings`"

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem recently, removing the tag `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>` inside .csproj 
solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This error when away after re-entering my outdated source control account credentials ( VisualStudio 2017: **File** > **Account Settings...** ).